# PyInstaller and Python modules

Tags: python, import, module, bundle, pyinstaller

I'm currently trying to bundle my Python (3.4.4) application with PyInstaller. I'm following the PyInstaller documentation about how to build a .spec file.

This is how my project file tree looks like:

project/

- __init__.py
- main.py
- ui.py
- Lib/

  - __init__.py
  - History.py
  - Command.py
  - Graphics.py
  - Tools.py

According to the documentation, all I have to do is to run the `pyi-makespec main.py` function and the `Lib` module will be detected as long as it is imported from the `main.py` file.

Documentation:

> Because your script includes the statement import helpmod, PyInstaller will create this folder arrangement in your bundled app

https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#using-data-files-from-a-module

This is how the beginning of the my `main.py` looks like

```
# main.py
from Lib.Command import Command
from Lib.History import History
from Lib.Graphics import Graphics
import Lib.Tools as Tools
```

When I try to run the app afterwards, all I get is this error. I probably missed something, does someone have an idea of the problem ? :D

error log : http://pastebin.com/3dygTqfn

EDIT : Just figured out that the problem comes from my `Graphics.py` library, which import some bokeh tools I use to generate histograms. Still don't know why the bokeh import makes the whole thing crash, it works perfectly fine when I run it with a python interpreter...

Comment: I am not sure if this is going to work in your case, but I found that in similar cases, importing the "core" module directly usually solves the problem. Try `import Lib` as the first line in your `main.py`.

Comment: Actually I tried several way to import modules but none seems to work:
"from Lib import History", 
"import Lib", 
"import Lib.History" and
"import Lib.History as History"

Comment: Since you identified the culprit, you can include the missing package in your build as [hidden import](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports). However, I suspect it goes deeper than that. Do you get any import errors?